# I'm trying to create an event but I get a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

I want to create an event in C# but I'm getting this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in shei graii.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Server code:

```
public class mobile
{
    public delegate void chargeEvent();
    public event chargeEvent sampleEvent;

    private byte _charge;

    public byte charge
    {
        set
        {
            _charge = value;
            if (_charge <= 15)
            {
                sampleEvent(); // the error line
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
mobile mob = new mobile();

mob.charge = 14;

mob.sampleEvent += new mobile.chargeEvent(input);
```

Input code:

```
public void input()
{
    MessageBox.Show("battery low");
}
```

Comment: what u mean by this sampleEvent(); // the error line? Do you mean invoking the event?

Comment: yes i want to invoke a new event for my class

Comment: `sampleEvent?.Invoke();`. Maybe pass the current value as parameter (changing the delegate's declaration).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the `NullReference` error because you try to invoke the event before setting it. So try this instead:

```
mobile mob = new mobile();

mob.sampleEvent += new mobile.chargeEvent(input);

mob.charge = 14;
```

This is as far as we can go with the limited code you provided.

Comment: that worked,thanks!